# How to fix Zapier not showing all Dynamic Dropdown options that are presented in a JSON Array GET API Repsonse?

Tags: arrays, json, get, zapier, zapier-cli

I'm building a Zapier app for a platform that has dynamic fields that are specific to the individual user.

My API returns this response using a GET request:

```
[
    {
        "title": "003 Best Selling Book",
        "id": "d86cbdf41be958336f1221a2211c3f65",
        "date": "03/25/2021"
    },
    {
        "id": "b844eaa3da5c476ab7337e83775777e0",
        "title": "002 Best Selling Book",
        "date": "03/26/2021"
    }
]
```

The response is received by Zapier successfully

[Response received by Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZucx.png)

but it is only showing the first item in the JSON array.

[Only one object in my array shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bWwM.png)

When I go to test my trigger, it only shows me the one object in my array and give me a MISSING VALUE! error.

[Missing Value Error in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI6cw.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm trying to setup a Dropdown Type that is Dynamic and uses a Trigger to get the JSON object that populates the trigger.

[A screenshot of the settings for the my dropdown from the Form Editor on the Zapier Platform Input Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuw4M.png)

I tried looking for example code in the Zapier Github or elsewhere on Stackoverflow or the web that showed example JSON responses for Zapier Actions, Zapier Triggers and Zapier Dynamic Dropdowns but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#dynamic-dropdowns), your returned JSON needs `name` and `id` properties.

Comment: Hi @xavdid.

I figured out the issue. I needed to ad the name and id properties and also needed to make sure API responses were properly tagged.

Comment: Great!  If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).